# .net Sock.BeginReceive and block the EndReceive

Tags: .net

I used .Net's Socket.BeginReceive method ,while i get the data from EndReceive method i use the AutoResetEvent.waitone block the EndReceive code thread infinitely i found the BeginReceive can't work; all thread were blocked ; i get nothing until the timer finished and signaled the event i can get datas again. BeginReceive isn't a asynchronous method?

```
var sock= new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

sock.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 1024, SocketFlags.None, i => {
    var sock= (Socket)i.AsyncState;
    int readNum=sock.EndReceive(i);
    var reset= new AutoResetEvent(false);
    Timer timer = new Timer({ Thread.Sleep(1000000000); reset.set() });

    reset.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);
    time.Dispose();
} ,sock);
```

mere dispose the timer i must create new thread to wait!!

Comment: Could you post the relevant code please? BeginReceive is an asynchronous method and will only block on the thread it created and not your main application thread. I'm going to guess that your use of the `AutoResetEvent` is causing the problem here.

Comment: Add the code to your question, there is an edit link just underneath the tags =]

Comment: i just let the callback method wait AutoResetEvent after that i can't receive anything but when i set the AutoResetEvent i can receive data normally

Comment: `var sock= new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

sock.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 1024, SocketFlags.None, i=>{

  var s=  (Socket)i.AsyncState;
  int readNum=s.EndReceive(i);
  Timer timer = new Timer(...);

  var e= new AutoResetEvent(false);
  e.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);
  time.Dispose();
},sock);

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AutoResetEvent`, `e` is enclosed in a temporary closure so the thread that is created to deal with the `EndReceive` code will wait indefinitely.

You would be better off refactoring your code to something like this:

```
bool stopped = false;
var timer = null;

void MainFunction()
{
    var buffer = new byte[1024];
    var sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    sock.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 1024, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), sock);
}

void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var sock = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

    int readNum = sock.EndReceive(ar);

    // begin receiving again as long as we shouldn't be stopped
    if (stopped == false)
    {
        sock.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 1024, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), sock);
    }

    if (timer == null)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer({ Thread.Sleep(1000000000); stopped = true; });
    }
}
```

You will need to `Set` your `AutoResetEvent` to signal that the resource is free. I can't see any code for that in what you provided.

You might want to take a look at some of the examples and documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx

Comment: i can't understand is that i can receive data from other theads though EndReceive code will wait in one thread but now i receive nothing while one thread wait

Comment: Ah yes it's because you're using a shared `AutoResetEvent` and waiting on it for 1 million seconds. Is there any reason you have a 1 million second wait before that thread is allowed to receive again?

Comment: yes i must simulate a device ;it must do sometime in a tiemspan after  that it must stop;at same time i also want the device keep receive datas bu i found the receive thread can't work until the timespan end

Comment: Ok so how about you create a timer that is set off after the first thread starts to receive and then set a flag that other threads check before they begin receiving?

Comment: the EndReceive code run in different thread everytime why others thread can't receive datas i can't understand

Comment: Are you restarting the accept/receive process again after you've received the data? So you should call `Socket.BeginAccept`, which will then callback to `Socket.EndAccept` (or a simple blocking `Socket.Accept` will do) then call `BeginReceive` which calls back to `EndReceive` and once you've finished receiving the data (and possibly sending some back) you need to call `BeginAccept` (or `Accept`) again to accept a new socket connection.

Comment: the AutoResetEvent isn't shared it's created in a asynchronous thread so why other threads in threadpool can't keep receiving datas from server i can't understand

Comment: Yes but your initial socket that you're listening on is a shared socket, it's bound on one port and will handle all incoming TCP requests on that port, so you need to put it back into the "I'm waiting for a connection" state again before it can accept another connection.

Comment: Can you post all code that is using the Socket in your question? You must have some calls to `Accept` or `BeginAccept`somewhere =]

Comment: i only simulate client just connect BeginReceive EndReceive

Comment: Ok so the socket is only ever connected to one client at a time? In that case you should be able to just call `BeginReceive` again. I'll edit my answer to reflect =]

Comment: you describe complexly i just connect -> BeginReveive -> callback .

Comment: the callback will wait the timer finish it's work. you mean is that the callback take the socket it must be free？

Comment: Yes, it at least needs to start receiving again at the very least. Your timer shouldn't really be in that closure on its own.

Comment: yes,you are right. I must release the socket by calling BeginReceive method again when wait the AutoResetEvent. i have already solved the problem now. Thank you!